# Importing JSON into datagridview, but the first value is not being inserted [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, json.net

Im trying to import a json to datagridview in vb.net.

```
{ "data": 
 { "docdata": 
        { "Join": [ 
           { "Allocated": [ 
              { "dt": "19-04-2022", },
              { "dt": "30-04-2022", },
              { "dt": "03-05-2022", },
              { "dt": "13-06-2022", }, 
              { "dt": "07-07-2022", } 
              ]
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

the first "dt" value  which is 19-04-2-22 is not being adding to the datagridview, instead values are being inserted from 30-04-2022

```
  For i = 0 To Joincount - 1

                For j = 0 To jsonobject.SelectToken("data.docdata.Join")(i)("Allocated").Count - 1

                    FrmStart.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = jsonobject.SelectToken("data.docdata.Join")(i)("Allocated")(j)("dt")

                    'Console.WriteLine(jsonobject.SelectToken("data.docdata.Join")(i)("Allocated")(j)("dt"))

                Next

                '    crow += 1
       FrmStart.DataGridView1.Rows.Add()

  Next
```

In the debug window, "console.writeline" returns correct values. It is printing the first record, which is dated 19-04-2022. However, it is not inserting the same in gridview.

*I'm a beginner at coding. and my way of thinking is also in its early stages, so please advise me on the best way to deal with it.*

Comment: Have you though about moving this: `FrmStart.DataGridView1.Rows.Add()` a bit upstream? -- You should not be using default instances of Forms

Comment: Is it treating the first value as a header?

Comment: @Jimi, Yes. moved upstream. and result is same .

Comment: @ClearlyClueless but headers are intact. it still showing "Date" in header

Comment: Not that it is actually using the header but that its throwing it out as if it is one.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless , oh, how can i confirm that ? and if yes, how to resolve that ?

Comment: `FrmStart.DataGridView1(0, i + 1).Value = Jdate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy")`
i used this to test whether its using or not. its now given output like this "Date" "Blank Cell","30-Apr-2022"

Comment: You are only using `i` in your row reference for the datagridview. `i` never really gets incrememented as far as I can see whereas `j` is what is individually looping through the json to grab individual dt elements. Should you not being using j? We don't know what your grid structure looks like here, however I assume that you are trying to put all of these dates in different rows of the same column. With Rows(i) bound to the outer loop, it won't incremement until the inner is finished so you'll loop through the inner in its entirety before moving down a row.

Comment: Try running this BEFORE you do your grid insert `Console.WriteLine($"i: {i}{vbcr} j: {j} {vbcr} gridCellContent: {FrmStart.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value}{vbcr} jsonContent: {sonobject.SelectToken("data.docdata.Join")(i)("Allocated")(j)("dt")}{vbcr}------{vbcr}")` and then add the output of this to your original post.

Comment: hi i tried with different json. and part of result is this
```
i: 0
 j: 0 
 gridCellContent: 
 jsonContent: 01-07-2022
------

i: 0
 j: 1 
 gridCellContent: 01-Jul-22
 jsonContent: 08-07-2022
------

i: 0
 j: 2 
 gridCellContent: 01-Jul-22
 jsonContent: 09-07-2022
------

i: 0
 j: 3 
 gridCellContent: 01-Jul-22
 jsonContent: 16-07-2022
------

i: 0
 j: 4 
 gridCellContent: 01-Jul-22
 jsonContent: 21-07-2022
---

i: 1
 j: 0 
 gridCellContent: 08-Jul-22
 jsonContent: 08-07-2022

i: 1
 j: 1 
 gridCellContent: 08-Jul-22
 jsonContent: 15-07-2022

```

Comment: I've added the above to your OP as troubleshooting data, however you should really not change json in the middle of troubleshooting. please try again with the same data from previously. I've slightly modified the troubleshooting writeline and added it to you OP. Please use that one for simplicity of formatting it into a table here later!

Comment: Of course, all this would be pretty close to moot if you were to parse your json to a collection object (DataTable or List of(UAT) for example) and bind that to your DataGridView.  Makes an all-around simpler and more robust solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help others working with json objects.

Suggested solution after correcting the json string:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click

    Dim JsonData As String = "
        { ""data"": 
            { ""docdata"": 
                { ""Join"": 
                    [
                        { ""Allocated"": 
                            [ 
                                { ""dt"": ""19-04-2022"", },
                                { ""dt"": ""30-04-2022"", },
                                { ""dt"": ""03-05-2022"", },
                                { ""dt"": ""13-06-2022"", }, 
                                { ""dt"": ""07-07-2022"", } 
                            ]
                        } 
                    ]
                } 
            }
        } "

    Dim JsonObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(JsonData)

    For i = 0 To JsonObject.Count - 1

        For j = 0 To JsonObject.SelectToken("data.docdata.Join")(i)("Allocated").Count - 1

            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(JsonObject.SelectToken("data.docdata.Join")(i)("Allocated")(j)("dt"))

        Next

    Next

End Sub

End Class

Public Class Allocated
    Public Property dt As String
End Class

Public Class Join
    Public Property Allocated As Allocated()
End Class

Public Class Docdata
    Public Property Join As Join()
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property docdata As Docdata
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Property data As Data
End Class
```

Comment: I am glad you have it working. I do have a question.  The Json string you provided has a missing "]" on the { "Join": [

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your efforts.@user21031252, the problem still exists even with that method however it got fixed if i changed coding.

```
For i = 0 To Joincount - 1
   

    For j = 0 To jsonobject.SelectToken("data.docdata.Join")(i)("Allocated").Count - 1

                jdate = jsonobject.SelectToken("data.docdata.Join")(i)("Allocated")(j)("dt")

     Next
FrmStart.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Jdate)
Next
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).